# Multiple Join, Multiple where statement and multiple update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hi i made 2 queries to update some data. But i need to make it more simple. instead of making 2 queries i need to make one query. and the joins i have used, i need to use it only once. can any body help me with this:

Current Query:

```
USE DB02
GO

UPDATE TCC  
SET RANK = 'S'
FROM TOTAL_NEGO_HISTORY TNH 
    JOIN M_CONTRACT MC                  ON TNH.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
    JOIN T_DEPOSIT_ASSIGNED_LIST TDAL   ON TDAL.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID 
    JOIN T_DEPOSIT_HISTORY TDH          ON TDH.DEPOSIT_NO = TDAL.DEPOSIT_NO
    JOIN T_CREDIT_CONTRACT TCC          ON TCC.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
WHERE TDH.DEPOSIT_YMD = TNH.COMMITMENT_DATE
GO


UPDATE TCC
SET RANK = 'C2'
FROM TOTAL_NEGO_HISTORY TNH  
    JOIN M_CONTRACT MC                  ON TNH.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
    JOIN T_DEPOSIT_ASSIGNED_LIST TDAL   ON TDAL.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID 
    JOIN T_DEPOSIT_HISTORY TDH          ON TDH.DEPOSIT_NO = TDAL.DEPOSIT_NO
    JOIN T_CREDIT_CONTRACT TCC          ON TCC.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
WHERE TDH.DEPOSIT_MONEY = TNH.COMMITMENT_AMAOUNT
GO
```

Expected is something like bellow:

```
USE DB02
GO

UPDATE TCC  
SET RANK = 'S'  case WHEN TDH.DEPOSIT_YMD = TNH.COMMITMENT_DATE 
SET RANK = 'C2' case WHEN TDH.DEPOSIT_MONEY = TNH.COMMITMENT_AMAOUNT
FROM TOTAL_NEGO_HISTORY TNH 
    JOIN M_CONTRACT MC                  ON TNH.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
    JOIN T_DEPOSIT_ASSIGNED_LIST TDAL   ON TDAL.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID 
    JOIN T_DEPOSIT_HISTORY TDH          ON TDH.DEPOSIT_NO = TDAL.DEPOSIT_NO
    JOIN T_CREDIT_CONTRACT TCC          ON TCC.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
USE DB02
GO

UPDATE  TCC  
SET     RANK = (Case WHEN TDH.DEPOSIT_YMD = TNH.COMMITMENT_DATE Then 'S'
                    WHEN TDH.DEPOSIT_MONEY = TNH.COMMITMENT_AMAOUNT Then 'C2'
                    Else RANK   ----there should be else to handle case when properly
              End)
FROM    TOTAL_NEGO_HISTORY TNH 
        JOIN M_CONTRACT MC                  ON TNH.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
        JOIN T_DEPOSIT_ASSIGNED_LIST TDAL   ON TDAL.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID 
        JOIN T_DEPOSIT_HISTORY TDH          ON TDH.DEPOSIT_NO = TDAL.DEPOSIT_NO
        JOIN T_CREDIT_CONTRACT TCC          ON TCC.CONTRACT_ID = MC.CONTRACT_ID
GO
```

Comment: You can use `Else RANK` to leave the value as it was